# mobx @observable throws error on older Android 4.4 Tablet

Tags: javascript, android, mobx, mobx-react

I am loving mobx, and have implemented a small app on some tablets and ran into an issue with older javascript on the Android WebView (which I can't upgrade due to the age of the tablet).

Android Tablet: Nexus 4.4 (lollipop)

The error is below, though it looks like at around 2740 in the mobx.js file (function below) is having issues with @observables with older javascript engines.

I'm currently using webpack (see below) to transpile my js. Any help with this would be much appreciated as I really would like to use mobx moving forward.

Sincerely,
Chris

**line 2740 in mobx.js**

```
function isES6Map (thing) {
  if (thing instanceof getGlobal().Map) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

**console Error:**

[mobx] Catched uncaught exception that was thrown by a reaction or observer component, in: 'Reaction[CustomerFeedback#0.render()]
TypeError
message: "Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got locations-page"
stack: (...)
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
proto: Error
mobx.js:1284
Reaction.reportExceptionInDerivation

**webpack:**

```
'use strict';

const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const copyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const extractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

const scssLoaders = [
  'css-loader',
  'postcss-loader',
  'sass-loader?indentedSyntax=false&includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './application')
];

const config = {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './index.js'],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ['babel-loader'],
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          plugins: [
            'transform-decorators-legacy',
            'transform-class-properties',
            'mobx-deep-action'
          ],
          presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react'],
          babelrc: false
        }
      },
      {
        test: /.scss$/,
        loader: extractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', scssLoaders.join('!'))
      },
      {
        test: /.(svg|jpg|png)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=/media/[name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
    publicPath: '/build',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new extractTextPlugin('[name].css')

  ],

  postcss: [
    autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions']
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss'],
    modulesDirectories: ['./node_modules/'],
    root: [path.join(__dirname, './application')]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

**appState File:**

```
import { action, computed, extendObservable, toJS } from 'mobx';

class CustomerFeedbackState {
  constructor() {
    // Initializes all observables
    this.initializeStoreData();
  }

  /* ACTIONS */
  // Initialize the store's state, allowing a reinitialization of the app as needed (reset to default state)
  @action initializeStoreData() {
    extendObservable(this, {
      // Keeps track of what page the user is on - 'locations-page' is the start page
      currentPageName: 'locations-page',

      // Keeps track of what question is being asked
      currentQuestionNumber: 0,

      // Set to true when the JSON data comes back successful
      dataFetched: false,

      // sets the active state for the next button
      disableNextPage: true,

      // Keeps track of page history
      lastPageVisitedArray: [],

      // Current Location Id
      locationId: 0,

      // Mood link active states
      moodLinkHappyIsActive: false,
      moodLinkNeutralIsActive: false,
      moodLinkSadIsActive: false,

      // Next page available
      nextPage: '',

      // User mood
      userMood: ''
    });
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you actually using `babel-polyfill` in your code? `import "babel-polyfill";`

Comment: yes @Tholle, that is in the webpack.config: entry: ['babel-polyfill', './index.js'],

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Very interesting. Might be worth [**creating an issue**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/new)?

Comment: UpdatE: This was fixed with the mobx 3.0.2 release. I'll update the question above as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed with the 3.0.2 release last week (per feedback from the mobx developers).